# Getting job in US on B1/B2 visa

Tags: us-citizens, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, h1b-visas, working-visas

I have a B1/B2 visa to US, can i stay in US as a citizen and for how long?Can i apply for jobs there in US on this visa? What are the chances to get a job there?

Can i apply for an H1-B visa while my stay in US on B1/B2 visa?

Comment: The simple answer is "no, you cannot".  B1/B2 is a **visitor** visa, which means you can visit the USA for pleasure or existing business, but you cannot stay in the USA searching for a job.

Comment: Having a US visa doesn't make you a US citizen, nor can you stay in the US "as a citizen" unless you *are* a citizen. In every country I'm aware of, staying there on a visa and staying as a citizen are mutually exclusive, as citizens are neither required to have a visa nor eligible to get a visa for their own country. I think the [us-citizens] tag on this question should probably be removed unless you actually are a US citizen, in which case your US visa is invalid.